# SQL Server Getting where an data object was based in a Period of Time given Track Info

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a doubt on how to conclude this in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table that has some inputs and this inputs have a Parent tag and a timestamp.

Sometimes these objects have their parent Tag changed in a timestamp. This parent tag can change from time to time.
 Let´s suppose that I have the table below. My current table has millions of data with different ObjectIDs. Seeing the Table, it is easy to see that the ParentID was changed in the timestamps 3 to 4, 6 to 7 and 8 to 9.

> 

```
ProductID      ParentID       DateID          value
--------       ---------      -------         ------------- 
  100            1              1                325,2
  100            1              2                326,2
  100            1              3                329,6
  100            2              4                335,2
  100            2              5                336,5
  100            2              6                338,3
  100            3              7                339,2
  100            3              8                342,1
  100            1              9                343,7
  100            1              10               355,6
  100            1              11               385,8
```

The Answer I want is to which ParentID the ObjectID belonged and the Start and End timestamp and what was the delta value between the timestamps (Timestamp = TS)

> 

```
ProductID      ParentID       DateID_Start   DateID_End   DeltaValue
  --------      ---------     ----------     --------     ---------- 
  100           1             1              4            10,0
  100           2             4              7            4,0
  100           3             7              9            4,5
  100           1             9              11           42,1
```

What I have Accomplish so far is getting when there is a change, but it only gives me the changes, but not the table above.

> 

```
ObjectID      ParentID_Old   ParentID_New    DateID_Changed   
  --------      ------------   ------------  ------------
  100           1              2              3 to 4
  100           2              3              6 to 7
  100           3              1              8 to 9
```

Here are the code to generate the table and the test inserts. Below as well is the Select to get the changes.

```
        --Initial Insert Code
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Trackings') Is Not Null
    Drop table #Trackings

 Create Table #Trackings
 (
   ProductID bigint
 , value    float
 , StoreID  int
 , DateID int
 , Aux_Row_Number int
 )

Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,1,325.2,1)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,2,326.2,2)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,3,329.6,3)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,4,335.2,4)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,5,336.5,5)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,6,338.3,6)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,7,339.2,7)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,8,342.1,8)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,9,343.7,9)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,10,355.0,10)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,12,385.0,12)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,13,485.0,13)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,14,985.0,14)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,15,1585.0,15)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,16,3585.0,16)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,17,5585.0,17)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,18,6585.0,18)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,19,8585.0,19)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,20,9585.0,20)
```

And the SQL to get the changes I am using:

```
Select      ISNULL(A.StoreID,-1)
,           ISNULL(B.StoreID,-1)
,           A.ProductID
,           A.value
,           B.value
,           A.DateID
,           B.DateID
From        #Trackings A
Join        #Trackings B
On          A.ProductID = B.ProductID
And         A.Aux_Row_Number + 1 = B.Aux_Row_Number
And         ISNULL(A.StoreID,-1) <> ISNULL(B.StoreID,-1)
```

Any lights ideas Guys?

Thanks in advance!

EDITED: Just a little bit more "Business" info: ParentID would be like a store a product is and DateID the Time that it arrived there. So let's suppose that productID 100 is in the ParentID 1, it means that in the DateID 1 the productID 100 entered in Store 1. So for some reason it moved to Store 2 in DatedID 4. So my first row in the answer table means that ProductID 100 was in the StoreID 1 from DateID 1 up to DateID 4. The productID 100 then stayed in StoredID 2 from DateID 4 up to 7, then changed to StoredID 3 and finally it came back to StoreID 1 from DateID 9 up to our last DateID in the DateID range "selected". So that's why the answer table has 2 lines with ParentID 1.

Comment: In your answer table the logic for the last row is different that the first three rows. the `TSID_End` on row 4 is coming from a record with the same parent. On the other rows it is coming from the first record of the next parent.   Is this the expected result?

Comment: There is good details here, but there's a bit of a disconnect between the examples and the actual sample data, e.g. `ObjectID` and `ProductID`, `Aux_Row_Number`... It would be most useful to have consistent data and table structures between these different parts of the question.

Comment: @Declan-k The Result is like because it is the last Aux_Row_Number available :). So in the interval selected, the result does not give me more options and we need to just add in the TSID_End the last available number in the interval.

Comment: @IanPreston Thanks Man to pointing my silly mistake! Edited: objectId replaced for ProductID to be consistent! Aux_Row_Number will be used because I have different ProductsIDs and as so far I found it necessary, but you were right, I didn't gave more details about it. When I finally solve my issue I will update the posts below and check! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that based on my Initial Table has a better performance than using CTE and as sugested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2522030/mike-abramczyk (the real table has 5k entries and using the his suggestion was taking a long time).

After querying the search table, I added two lines to the table for each ProductID. These lines would receive a dummy StoreID (i.e. -9999): one with a Min(DateID) - 1 and another One with a Max(DateID) + 1.

```
Insert into #Trackings (Aux_Row_Number,StoreID,DateID,ProductID,value)
Select Min(Aux_Row_Number)-1 Aux_Row_Number,-9999 as StoreID, min(DateID)-1 as DateID,ProductID,Min(value)
From #Trackings
group by ProductID
Order by ProductID

Insert into #Trackings (Aux_Row_Number,StoreID,DateID,ProductID,value)
Select Max(Aux_Row_Number)+1 Aux_Row_Number,-9999 as StoreID, max(DateID)+1 as DateID,ProductID,Max(value)
From #Trackings
group by ProductID
Order by ProductID
```

Then, I used the Query I posted to get the changes. So I could get the Change from Dummy(-9999) to the real StoreID (1) and the last change from a real StoreID(3) to Dummy(-9999).

```
select      ISNULL(A.StoreID,-1)
,           ISNULL(B.StoreID,-1)
,           A.ProductID
,           A.value
,           B.value
,           A.DateID
,           B.DateID
,           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by B.ProductID Order by A.DateID)
from            #Trackings A
Join            #Trackings B
On              A.ProductID = B.ProductID
And             A.Aux_Row_Number + 1 = B.Aux_Row_Number
AND             ISNULL(A.StoreID,0) <> ISNULL(B.StoreID ,0)
```

This was the Crucial Step! Now I have I can create the result table with the DateIDs of the changes I was looking for. The Aux_Row_Number Column helped get a sequence in the changes to each product using (think that the last query has create the table #ProductStoreChanges - I will be posting the entire Soltion below):

```
select              A.ID_FinalStore,A.DateID_Final,B.DateID_Final,A.ProductID,B.value_2,A.value_2,B.value_2 - A.value_2 DeltaValue
from                #ProductStoreChanges A
Join                #ProductStoreChanges B
On                  (A.Aux_Row_Number + 1 = B.Aux_Row_Number) 
And                 A.ProductID = B.ProductID
Order by            A.DateID_Final
```

Here is the Final Solution:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Trackings') Is Not Null
    Drop table #Trackings

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ProductStoreChanges') Is Not Null
    Drop table #ProductStoreChanges

 Create Table #Trackings
 (
   ProductID bigint
 , value    float
 , StoreID  int
 , DateID int
 , Aux_Row_Number int
 , flg_changed bit Default(0)
 )

Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,1,325.2,1)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,2,326.2,2)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,3,329.6,3)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,4,335.2,4)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,5,336.5,5)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,6,338.3,6)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,7,339.2,7)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,8,342.1,8)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,9,343.7,9)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,10,355.0,10)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,12,385.0,12)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,13,485.0,13)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,14,985.0,14)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,15,1585.0,15)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,16,3585.0,16)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,17,5585.0,17)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,18,6585.0,18)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,19,8585.0,19)
Insert into #Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,20,9585.0,20)

Insert into #Trackings (Aux_Row_Number,StoreID,DateID,ProductID,value)
Select Min(Aux_Row_Number)-1 Aux_Row_Number,-9999 as StoreID, min(DateID)-1 as DateID,ProductID,Min(value)
From #Trackings
group by ProductID
Order by ProductID

Insert into #Trackings (Aux_Row_Number,StoreID,DateID,ProductID,value)
Select Max(Aux_Row_Number)+1 Aux_Row_Number,-9999 as StoreID, max(DateID)+1 as DateID,ProductID,Max(value)
From #Trackings
group by ProductID
Order by ProductID

 CREATE TABLE #ProductStoreChanges
 (
            ID_InitialStore         INT
  ,         ID_FinalStore           INT  
  ,         ProductID                   INT
  ,         value_1                 BIGINT 
  ,         value_2                 BIGINT 
  ,         DateID_Initial          BIGINT
  ,         DateID_Final            BIGINT 
  ,         Aux_Row_Number          INT
 )

INSERT INTO #ProductStoreChanges 
(   
            ID_InitialStore
  ,         ID_FinalStore       
  ,         ProductID               
  ,         value_1         
  ,         value_2         
  ,         DateID_Initial
  ,         DateID_Final
  ,         Aux_Row_Number      
)

select      ISNULL(A.StoreID,-1)
,           ISNULL(B.StoreID,-1)
,           A.ProductID
,           A.value
,           B.value
,           A.DateID
,           B.DateID
,           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by B.ProductID Order by A.DateID)
from            #Trackings A
Join            #Trackings B
On              A.ProductID = B.ProductID
And             A.Aux_Row_Number + 1 = B.Aux_Row_Number
AND             ISNULL(A.StoreID,0) <> ISNULL(B.StoreID ,0)


select              A.ID_FinalStore,A.DateID_Final,B.DateID_Final,A.ProductID,B.value_2,A.value_2,B.value_2 - A.value_2 DeltaValue
from                #ProductStoreChanges A
Join                #ProductStoreChanges B
On                  (A.Aux_Row_Number + 1 = B.Aux_Row_Number) 
And                 A.ProductID = B.ProductID
Order by            A.DateID_Final
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, try this, using your updated sample data:

```
Declare @Trackings table
 (
   ProductID bigint
 , value    float
 , StoreID  int
 , DateID int
 , Aux_Row_Number int
 )

Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,1,325.2,1)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,2,326.2,2)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,3,329.6,3)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,4,335.2,4)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,5,336.5,5)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,6,338.3,6)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,7,339.2,7)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,8,342.1,8)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,9,343.7,9)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,10,355.0,10)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,1,12,385.0,12)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,13,485.0,13)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,14,985.0,14)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,15,1585.0,15)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,3,16,3585.0,16)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,17,5585.0,17)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,18,6585.0,18)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,19,8585.0,19)
Insert into @Trackings(ProductID,StoreID,DateID,value,Aux_Row_Number) Values (100,2,20,9585.0,20)
 ;
with t
as (select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by dateid) as rn
from @Trackings ),

cte1 
    (Productid, 
    Storeid, 
    DateID,
    value,
    rn,
    set1)
as 
    (select ProductID, StoreID, DateID, value, rn , 1
    from  t
    where rn = 1
union all
    select t.productID, t.storeID, t.dateID, t.value, t.rn, 
    case when 
        cte1.Storeid = t.storeID then cte1.set1 else cte1.set1+1 end
    from  t join cte1 on t.rn = cte1.rn+1)

 ,

t2 as (select Productid, Storeid, set1, MIN(CAST(DateID as int)) as tmi, max(dateid) as tma
from cte1
group by Productid, Storeid, set1)

select t3.Productid, t3.Storeid, t3.set1, t3.date_min, t3.date_max, u.value - t.value
from
(select a.Productid, a.Storeid, a.set1, a.tmi as date_min, coalesce(b.tmi, a.tma) as date_max
from t2 a left join t2 b
on a.set1 + 1 = b.set1) t3 join @Trackings t
on t3.date_min =  t.DateID
join @Trackings u
on t3.date_max = u.DateID
order by set1
```

The "Value" column confused me, as you are using commas (,) instead of periods (.) to separate the integer from the decimal part of your float.

Comment: Hey Mike. Thanks for helping me out. I am trying to modify your SQL Code to meet my needs here and it is not working. I Edited the post and added the "business rule" for this case. If I found a solution I will post here as well. Thanks.